# Get a specific content with explode() function

Tags: php

I have a php file called test.php
when executed, output will appear like this

```
<table> 
<tr> 
<td> 
<a href='user.php?id=lih_profil&kode=60gb7c8be7fbebeb57f888780878087' 
style='text-decoration:none;color:white'> 
<img src = 'profil / empty.jpg' width = '50 'height = '60' style = 'padding-right: 10px;' /> 
</a> 
</ td> 
<td> 
<a href='user.php?id=lih_profil&kode=60gb7c8be7fbebeb57f888780878087' style='text-decoration:none;color:white'> MYCONTENT </a> 
</ td > 
</ tr> 
</ table>
```

I want to take "MYCONTENT" with the expode() function
How to?

Comment: You're going to have to clarify your question. And next time, please, format your code in to multiple lines.

Comment: Note you may be `implode()`-ing instead - depends on what format is your data in.  Give a sample.

Comment: Explode may not be suitable for your problem. You need to use `regex` or `dom parser` to get the value of `<a>`. btw if you do a `strip_tag()` you will still get the **MYCONTENT**

Comment: You don't parse HTML with string functions, certainly not `explode()`. Use `DomDocument`.